# Obtener id desde la url

Tags: php, pdo

Estyo mandando el id por la url, en la vista de mi navegador se muestra de esta manera

> localhost/talvez%20empresa/chat/index.php?id=4

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero que esa id de la url se pueda obtener desde otro fichero que es llamado por index.php

mi index.php es el siguiente

```
<?php session_start();

include 'db.php';
include '../functions.php';

$emit = obtener_mensajes($conexion, $us);

comprobarSession();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
        function ajax(){
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                }
            }

            req.open('GET', 'chat.php', true);
            req.send();

        }

        setInterval(function(){
            ajax()
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="ajax();">

<div id="container">
    <div id="chat_box">
        <div id="chat"></div>
    </div>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="nombre" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']['nombre']?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send it">
        <?php foreach ($emit as $msg): ?>   
        <input type="hidden" name="idReceiver" value="<?php echo $msg['idEmitter']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="idEmitter" value="<?php echo $us ?>">
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </form>
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['nombre'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $emitter = $_POST['idEmitter'];
    $receiver = $_POST['idReceiver'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO messages (nombre, message, idEmitter, idReceiver, seenUsuario) VALUES ('$name', '$message', '$emitter', '$receiver', '0')";

    $run = $conexion->query($query);
}

?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

y mi chat.php

es el siguiente

```
<?php session_start();

include 'db.php';
require_once '../functions.php';

comprobarSession(); 

?>



<?php 

$query = "SELECT ue.idUsuario, ue.nombre, ur.nombre, c.sent, c.message FROM messages c
              INNER JOIN usuarios ue ON c.idEmitter = ue.idUsuario
              INNER JOIN usuarios ur ON c.idReceiver = ur.idUsuario
              WHERE (c.idEmitter = 1 AND c.idReceiver = $us)
              or (c.idEmitter = $us AND c.idReceiver = 1)";

$run = $conexion->query($query);

while ($row = $run->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
    //var_dump($row);

?>

        <div id="chat_data">
            <span style="color: green;"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?> </span><br>
            <span style="color: brown;"><?php echo $row['message']; ?></span>
            <span style="float: right;"><?php echo fecha($row['sent']); ?></span>
        </div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

lo que quiero es poder obtener la id de la url en chat.php para poder colocarla en el query, exactamente en donde tiene el numeo 1

no he logrado encontrar la manera en que lo pueda conseguir... espero alguien me pueda ayudar

> **EDICION**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este ha sido el nuevo codigo

```
<?php session_start();

include 'db.php';
require_once '../functions.php';

comprobarSession(); 
$id=$_GET['id'];
var_dump($id);
?>



<?php 

$sql="
        SELECT ue.nombre de, ur.nombre a, c.message FROM  messages c
    INNER JOIN usuarios ue ON c.idEmitter = ue.idUsuario
    INNER JOIN usuarios ur ON c.idReceiver = ur.idUsuario
    WHERE (c.idEmitter = usr1 AND c.idReceiver = :usr2)
    OR (c.idEmitter = :usr2 AND c.idReceiver = usr1)";



/**
 *  Pruebas 
 *  En el código  se usa  PDO y  consultas preparadas
*/


$usr1=$id;
$usr2=$us;

$stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam("usr1",$usr1);
$stmt->bindParam("usr2",$usr2);
$stmt ->execute();

$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
imprimir ($arrDatos);

function imprimir($arrDatos)
{

    if ($arrDatos)
    {
        echo "<hr />SE ENCONTRARON  ".count($arrDatos). " REGISTROS<br /><hr />";
        /**
         *  Construímos los datos  de forma limpia
        */
        $strHtml='CHAT:<br />';    
        foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
        {
            $strHtml.='<span>'.$row["de"].': </span>'.$row["mensaje"].'<br />';
        }
        echo $strHtml;
    }
}
```

Y esto lo que imprime en pantalla index.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la Url sigue siendo la misma

> localhost/talvez%20empresa/chat/index.php?id=1

Y si cambio a `localhost/talvez%20empresa/chat/chat.php?id=1`

no se muestra nada

Comment: No creo que sea necesaria la etiqueta `PDO` para esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas lo siguiente:

#### En `index.php`:

Recuperar en JavaScript el valor id que quieres postear.

Supongo que se trata de este: 
`<input type="hidden" name="idReceiver" value="<?php echo $msg['idEmitter']; ?>">`

Puedes ponerle un tag  `id` para que lo recuperes más fácil en Javascript. Algo así:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="myId" name="idReceiver" value="<?php echo $msg['idEmitter']; ?>">
```

Luego lo recuperas en JS, para pasárselo a `chat.php`.

Tu función ajax debería quedar así más o menos:

```
    function ajax(){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = req.responseText;
            }
        }

        var myId=document.getElementById('myId');
        var url='chat.php?id='+myId;

        req.open('GET', url, true);
        req.send();

    }
```

De ese mode debería tener una url de chat.php parecida a esta: `/chat.php?id=1`

#### En `chat.php`:

```
...
$id=isset($_POST['id']);
if ($id)
{

... Todo el código de la base de datos
... Usa consultas preparadas como te expliqué en otra pregunta
... Y usa fetchAll para obtener un array asociativo, no fetch:

while ($row = $run->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):

}else{
echo "No se recibió la variable id";
}
```

Comment: PERO CHAT.PHP ES SOLICITADO POR EL INDEX.PHP, DE TODAS MANERAS, LO HE HECHO COMO ME INDICAS Y SIGUE IGUAL, Y LA URL SIGUE SIENDO LA MISMA

Comment: Bien la manera en que me indicaste que lo hiciera funciona, pero solo si entro a `ruta/chat/chat.php?id=1` lo cual no es lo correcto, ya que por defecto entra a `chat/index.php?id=1`

Comment: Porque no terminas de aclararte con la ubicación de tus archivos. No sé si `index.php` y `chat.php` están en la misma carpeta. Luego, tu función `ajax`  que debería enviar los datos a `chat.php` por lo que veo, es llamada en el `body` del documento HTML. Quizá cuando la misma es llamada todavía la variable que recoge el id del emisor no tiene valores. ¿No podrías tener en tu HTML algún botón desde el cual lances la acción de la función `ajax` al hacer click en él?

Comment: claro, index y chat.php pertenecen a la misma carpeta

Comment: he editado mi pregunta